# How to prove show that $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I  wanted  to  show  that  $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$  is  isomorphic  to $ \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

I first  tried  to  find  a  surjective  in  which  kernel  is  $\{0\}$.  But  I  failed,  so  I  was  a  little  confused  about  whether  these  two  sets  are  isomorphic  to  each  other  or  not.  So  can  it  be  first  shown  that  the  sets  cannot  be  non  isomorphic  or  something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Interpret $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as the multiplicative group $\{\pm 1\}$ and look at $$\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}, \; \; (x, \pm 1) \mapsto \pm e^x$$

Comment: Very Good answer +1

Answer (score 6):

First, note that you want to prove that these two **groups** are isomorphic, but your post says **sets**. Remember, a group is a set together with an operation, and the operation is crucial to what the group is; you should make sure you understand what the operation is for each group before you proceed.

The operation for $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is presumably $\cdot$ (i.e., multiplication), so that for example, given $3,7\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, we have $3\cdot 7=21$, and the operation on $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ is presumably addition in each coordinate, so that for example
$$(5.3,1)+(-1.1,1)=(4.2,0)$$
(since $1+1=0$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_2$).

Now, understand your goal: you want to find an isomorphism between these two groups, i.e. a function $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ that is a **group homomorphism** and **bijective**.

To be a group homomorphism, for any $x,y\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ the function $f$ should satisfy
$$f(x\cdot y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
which is the well-known property that the **logarithm** function $\log:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies. The function $\log$ is also a bijection from $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This gives you a hint that you can use the logarithm to define your desired group isomorphism $f$.

To deal with negative numbers, use the factor of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and define $f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ like this:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\hphantom{-}(\log(x),0) & \text{ if }x>0\\
(\log(-x),1) & \text{ if }x<0
\end{cases}$$
This function is the **inverse** of the function from user362705's answer.